# Querying DB in Python3 throws ascii codec can't decode byte error

Tags: python, postgresql, ascii, psycopg2

I am using running python 3.8.6 (on aws lambda) and connecting to a postgres databse using psycopg2. The use case is to connect to the DB, run a query and save this query to a csv file. The databse is quite big and there seems to be non ascii character in the database that is causing some issues when I have processed about 3/4 of the files as I am getting the following error message:

```
"errorMessage": "'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)",
"errorType": "UnicodeDecodeError",
```

Based on the errors I have tried reviewing the docs to help mitigate the issue and taken on some of the suggestions, however I am still encountering the issue. The code is quite lengthy, however the latest version including some previously followed suggestions for the the database parts are as follows:

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extensions

psycopg2.extensions.register_type(psycopg2.extensions.UNICODE)
psycopg2.extensions.register_type(psycopg2.extensions.UNICODEARRAY)
.
.
try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(host=db_host, user=db_username, password=db_password, database=db_name)
.
.
def run_sql():
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute(open(sql_file_location, 'r', encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore").read())
        with open(csv_filename_location, mode='w', encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
            csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
             for row in cur:
                csv_writer.writerow(list(row))
        conn.commit()
```

The error occurs when looping through the returned results:

```
 line 167, in run_sql\n for row in cur:\n"
```

Some further information that I noted is that the Lambda is running utf-8 and the database returns `SQLASCII` when running `conn.encoding` and returns `SQL_ASCII` when running `conn.cursor()fetchone()[0]`

I think the symbol in the database may be a '€' symbol or something similar so if anyone has any suggestions on changes to make to account for this I would be very appreciative.

Comment: 1) This: `cur.execute(open(sql_file_location, 'r', encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore").read())` looks like a foot gun,  especially the `errors="ignore"`.  2) Use `psql` and connect to database to see what `show server_encoding ;` and `show client_encoding ;` return. *Add as update to question* 3) Not sure how `conn.cursor()fetchone()[0]` returns `SQL_ASCII` much less anything else? 4) If the database is actually `SQL_ASCII` then all bets are off as that essentially means no encoding.

Comment: 1) This was after some changes, the original code was simply ```cur.execute(open(sql_file_location, 'r').read())```. I though ignoring the errors would allow me to skip the record giving the error. I will work on 2 and 3.
4) If it is actually ```SQL_ASCII``` is there anything that can be done?

Comment: See here [Character Sets](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/multibyte.html) and search for `SQL_ASCII` for description of what is going on or more correctly not going on. The issue is you really have no way of knowing what encoding non-ASCII characters belong to. This means detective work to find out what was put in database and with what encoding. My experience is it usually one the many Windows code pages.

Comment: Thank you @AdrianKlaver for your help, the DB was using ```SQL_ASCII```, but it was actually my fault in the connection that caused all of my issues. When I did ```conn.set_client_encoding("utf-8")```  for the connection, it solved the issue. I wouldn't have found it without you setting me on the right path!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To those in the future stuck on the same issue I had, the Database I was connecting to was in fact using `SQL_ASCII`, I had missed one step when declaring my connection in order to use `utf-8` in my environment. Below is the one line added after the connection is made:

```
try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(host=db_host, user=db_username, password=db_password, database=db_name)
    conn.set_client_encoding("utf-8")
```